# Is there a data structure that allows storing more than two elements?

Tags: c++, list, data-structures

So, what I am searching for would maybe look like this (without the `xxx`):

```cpp
const xxx<std::string, std::string, void (*)(std::string)> commands = {
  {"exit", "Exit Program", f1},
  {"test", "Start Test", f2},
  {"help, h", "Help Screen", f3}
};
```

As far as I know, lists, vectors, maps, etc. can't do that. Is there anything I can just replace the `xxx` with? Or is there an easy other way to do it?

Comment: It looks like you want a `std::tuple`.

Comment: I think the std::tuple works perfect here, but thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a basic level, you can use [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple): `std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::function<void(std::string)> command` which can hold any number of types.

If you want more than one, use a `std::vector<std::tuple<...>>`:

```cpp
using Command = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::function<void(std::string)>>;
using CommandList = std::vector<Command>;

CommandList commands;
```

For more advanced compositions, a custom user-defined type is easier, but for only three types it's not really worth it.